# Wrong top left coordinates when drawing rectangle in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am developing an web app and in this page, the user could draw a rectangle once a button is clicked. However, when you click a button and you draw the rectangle, the top left coordinates of the rectangle is way-off the starting point of our drawing. It is in way lower than it has to be.

Here is my html :

```
<form action="/add_bounding_box" method="post" id="addBoundingBoxForm">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="enableDrawing()">Start Drawing</button>
  <div class="form-group mt-2">
     <label for="new_class_id_add">Select Class ID:</label>
     <select name="new_class_id_add" class="form-control" required>
        {% for id in all_class_ids %}
        <option value="{{id}}">{{id}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
     </select>
  </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="drawing_coordinates" id="drawing_coordinates">
 <button type="submit" style="display: none;"></button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="addBoundingBox()">Add Bounding Box</button>
</form>
```

Here is my Javascript :

```
ar drawingEnabled = false;
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rectStart = {};
var drawingCoordinates = [];

function enableDrawing() {
    drawingEnabled = true;
    canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
}

function addBoundingBox() {
    if (!drawingEnabled) {
        alert("Please start drawing first.");
        return;
    }

    drawingEnabled = false;
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";

    // Store the drawing coordinates
    document.getElementById("drawing_coordinates").value = JSON.stringify(drawingCoordinates);

    // Submit the form
    document.getElementById("addBoundingBoxForm").submit();
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    
    if (!drawingEnabled) return;
    
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    rectStart = {
        x: e.clientX - rect.left + window.scrollX,
        y: e.clientY - rect.top + window.scrollY,
    };

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drawRect);

    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
        canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", drawRect);
    });
});


function drawRect(e) {
    var rectEnd = { x: e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left, y: e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top };
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeRect(rectStart.x, rectStart.y, rectEnd.x - rectStart.x, rectEnd.y - rectStart.y);

    // Store the drawing coordinates
    drawingCoordinates = [rectStart.x / canvas.width, rectStart.y / canvas.height,
     (rectEnd.x - rectStart.x) / canvas.width,
     (rectEnd.y - rectStart.y) / canvas.height];
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: What templating library is this?

Comment: Where did you see you need to add `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY`? `getBoundingClientRect()`  and `clientX` are both relative to the viewport, the scrolling amount doesn't matter.